# Log Shipping and Ola's Hallengren's Scripts - Can they work in unison?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, log-shipping, ola-hallengren

I have a single instance database server with several databases.  Some do not require log shipping and some do require log shipping.

Is there a way to edit Ola's LOG backup job to ignore the databases I have configured for log shipping and backup all the remaining log files?

The only way I can think to do this without turning up a new server or create a secondary instance is not using Ola's script and create my own custom maintenance plans.

Comment: There are arguments that you can use in the backup command for including and exclusing databases. Would that be a good option for you?

Comment: I believe Ola Hallengren's scripts automatically check for log shipped databases and just dont backup logs. will do full and diff though.  https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html

Comment: Wow, I must have missed that yesterday.  I was reading through his FAQ at the end of a very tedious day and never saw "The SQL Server Maintenance Solution supports log shipping. Full and differential backup, integrity check, and index and statistics maintenance are performed on the primary database. Transaction log backups are not performed on databases that are involved in log shipping."  Control-F "shipping" does wonder to search his site...